# SQL Server : string to rows with delimiter?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, rows, delimiter

In SQL Server 2016 there is a function called `STRING_SPLIT` (Transact-SQL).

Answer to my question would work fine with this function.

Unfortunately we only have SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT 
    email,
    [Special ftg],
    [Special OrgCode],
    [Special SalaryCode]
FROM 
    Employee
```

How can I get this?

[image]

```
email             Special ftg                             Special OrgCode    Special SalaryCode 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test@gmail.com    4;200;210;220;250;275;1100;1101;1102    14000000000          1
```

into this:

[image]

The delimiter is semicolon and it should be that for all columns.

Comment: Plenty of stuff if you search for it online, [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) being one of them.

Comment: I have search online but did not found a simple solution. 
There for i asked a question. Your link is for me not easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `[Special ftg]`  into XML ant then use OUTER APPLY:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  email,
        CAST('<p>'+REPLACE([Special ftg],';','</p><p>')+'</p>'as xml) as [Special ftg],
        [Special OrgCode],
        [Special SalaryCode]
FROM Employee
)

SELECT  c.email,
        t.c.value('.','int') [Special ftg],
        NULL [Special OrgCode],
        NULL [Special SalaryCode]
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY [Special ftg].nodes('/p') as t(c)
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.email,
        NULL,
        c.[Special OrgCode],
        NULL
FROM cte c
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.email,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        c.[Special SalaryCode]
FROM cte c
ORDER BY email,[Special SalaryCode],[Special OrgCode],[Special ftg]
```

Output:

```
email           Special ftg Special OrgCode Special SalaryCode
test@gmail.com  4           NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  200         NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  210         NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  220         NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  250         NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  275         NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  1100        NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  1101        NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  1102        NULL            NULL
test@gmail.com  NULL        14000000000     NULL
test@gmail.com  NULL        NULL            1
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. 
I tried to change your script a bit but i get an error. 

SELECT 
A.[email], 
Split.A.value(';', 'NVARCHAR(300)') AS [Special ftg]
FROM 
 (SELECT email, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE ([Special ftg], ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS string
  FROM Employee) AS A
CROSS APPLY string.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A)
ORDER BY 1,2

The ERROR is this:
XQuery [A.string.value()]: Syntax error near ';'

Comment: `split.A.value('.',...` There must be . not ;

Comment: Perfect thank you. I will mark your answer as correct :)